# Get layers weights as network output keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

I have an autoencoder model, where I would like to get the weights W of the dense layer in the middle: I have to set some elements to zeros, and use it in the loss function.

basically

```
x = Encoder()(input)
z = Dense(units=10)(x)
out = Decoder()(z)
```

and the loss should have the following interface

```
loss(input, out, z, w)
```

there `w` are the weights of the dense layer. 
Any idea how?

Additionally, I'd like to enforce the diagonal of W to be zero. I saw Tensorflow has a matrix_set_diag function, any experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't throw the reference to Dense() away. For example:

```
x = Encoder()(input)
layer = Dense(units=10)
z = layer(x)
out = Decoder()(z)

print(layer.kernel)
```

will give you the layer's kernel

Comment: problem is that i cannot return a layer as output of the network and get_weights() returns an empty list

Comment: and K.cast(layer.get_weights()[0], dtype='float32') wont work too

TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: Tensor("Cast/x:0", shape=(8, 8), dtype=float32

Comment: Why does the layer need to be the output of the network? The value of the layer doesn't change depending on the inputs.

Comment: But it changes during training ... I need it to compute the loss

Comment: Why do you need the weights for the loss? Is it a regularizer? keras has a way to specify those

Comment: It is a regularizer but i need to combine it with the data too. Here is the paper papers.nips.cc/paper/6608-deep-subspace-clustering-networks